# Correct usage of std::atomic

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, stdatomic

Is this the correct way to use std::atomic? I have a single `Logger` declared at namespace level called `LOGGER`:

```
class Logger {
    public:

    Logger();
    ~Logger();

    bool Init(std::wstring logFileLocation);
    bool Shutdown();

    void const LogMessage(std::wstring message);
};

std::atomic<Logger&> LOGGER;
```

My expectation is that `LOGGER` will instantiated once (no races; it will be initialized from a single known point in the code), but then accessed from multiple threads.

I'm new to multi-threading and thread safety in C++; but in C# or Java I would like to either make `LOGGER` **volatile** or (in C#) put memory fences around it. Is this the correct analogue in C++?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`std::atomic<T>` provides synchronization for the operations that are defined in the `atomic` template. That includes storing a value of type `T`, getting the value of type `T`, swapping a value of type `T` with the `T` in the atomic object, and a handful of compare and exchange operations. It is **not** a replacement for proper synchronization of operations on the contained object. In particular, calling `LogMessage` from multiple threads will produce a data race if `LogMessage` doesn't protect its data with a mutex.

Comment: Right, but all threads will see all updates to the value stored in LOGGER, right? I didn't make it clear, sorry about that, but I'm only trying to ascertain whether or not std::atomic acts as a memory fence.

Comment: @Motig - if you store a new `LOGGER` object into the `atomic<LOGGER>` object, all threads that access the `atomic<LOGGER>` object will see the new value. They **won't** necessarily see **changes** to the contents of the stored object that result from calling its member functions. You need a mutex for that.

Comment: Thank you Pete; I understand that I need proper synchronization in the actual Logger implementation too, also. I'll accept your answer once I can.

Answer (score 1):

The `std::atomic` works on a "bag of bits": an object of type `T` whose bitwise representation, stored in `sizeof(T)` bytes, carries the whole value. It means that nothing that needs to atomically manipulated (by these specific operations on `std::atomic<T>`) can reside in an object pointed to by a member of `T`, that would never work.

Also it means that `std::atomic<T>` can only work for a concrete object type `T`. A reference type is an "alias" for another object: *a reference is not an object*.