# Correct usage of std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<T>> with non-trivial object?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++20, stdatomic

I'm trying to implement a lock-free wrapper via `std::atomic<std::shared_ptr>>` to operate over non-trivial objects like containers.
I found some relevant pieces of information in these two topics:

- [memory fence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62318642/should-combining-memory-fence-for-mutex-acquire-exchange-loop-or-queue-acquire)
- [atomic usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20640749/correct-usage-of-stdatomic)

But it still isn't what I need.

Give an example:

```
TEST_METHOD(FechAdd)
    {
        constexpr size_t loopCount = 5000000;
        auto&& container           = std::atomic<size_t>(0);
        auto thread1               = std::jthread([&]()
              {
                  for (size_t i = 0; i < loopCount; i++)
                      container++;
              });

        auto thread2 = std::jthread([&]()
            {
                for (size_t i = 0; i < loopCount; i++)
                    container++;
            });
        thread1.join();
        thread2.join();
        Assert::AreEqual(loopCount * 2, container.load());
    }
```

This function works correctly because the post-increment operator uses an internally `fetch_add()` atomic operation.

On the other hand:

```
TEST_METHOD(LoadStore)
{
    constexpr size_t loopCount = 5000000;
    auto&& container           = std::atomic<size_t>(0);
    auto thread1               = std::jthread([&]()
          {
              for (size_t i = 0; i < loopCount; i++)
              {
                  auto value = container.load();
                  value++;
                  container.store(value);
              }
          });

    auto thread2 = std::jthread([&]()
        {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < loopCount; i++)
            {
                auto value = container.load();
                value++;
                container.store(value);
            }
        });
    thread1.join();
    thread2.join();
    Assert::AreEqual(loopCount * 2, container.load());
}
```

Whereas if I replace it with `.load()` and `.store()` operations and incrementation between these two operations, the result is not the same.
That is two atomic operations, so synchronization cannot be done between these operations.

My ultimate goal through `std::atomic<std::shared_ptr>` loads the object's actual state, performs some non-const operation, and saves it by store operation again.

```
TEST_METHOD(AtomicSharedPtr)
{
    constexpr size_t loopCount = 5000000;
    auto&& container           = std::atomic(std::make_shared<std::unordered_set<int>>());
    auto thread1               = std::jthread([&]([[maybe_unused]] std::stop_token token)
          {
              for (size_t i = 0; i < loopCount; i++)
              {
                  // some other lock-free synchronization primitives as barrier, conditions or?
                  auto reader = container.load();
                  reader->emplace(5);
                  container.store(reader);
              }
          });

    auto thread2 = std::jthread([&]([[maybe_unused]] std::stop_token token)
        {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < loopCount; i++)
            {
                // some other lock-free synchronization primitives as barrier, conditions or?
                auto reader = container.load();
                reader->erase(5);
                container.store(reader);
            }
        });
}
```

I knew that the second thread also has only shared_ptr from atomic and non-const operations on shared_ptr, [which can only cause data race.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)

So any hint on how to implement a lock-free wrapper that will work with non-const operations of the object stored in `std::atomic<std::shared_ptr>`?

Comment: If you're looking for a way to make multithreaded access to any C++ class thread-safe without locking, I don't think that is possible.  If you're looking for something more specific, you might want to clarify what that is.

Comment: read-modify-write cannot be done atomically on arbitrary data without failures. You either need to add a retry loop to handle failures (hard, slow, and probably buggy), or use a lock (easy, fast, probably bugless).

Comment: Start with a standard locking mechanism. If profiling shows that the lock prevents the program meeting performance targets, then proceed to doing sneaky stuff. If the code meets performance targets, who cares if might be a little slower than the optimal ideal?

Comment: @user4581301 I've already done the template wrapper that used locking pattern, especially std::shared_mutex, to create concurrency over every stl container, but now I'm looking for any way how to do it without locking if any exists.

Comment: @VítJaneček: You really shouldn't be trying to "create concurrency over every stl container". Good concurrency needs to be a lot more coarse grained and a lot higher level than a mere container. Concurrency needs to ensure the meaning of data, which can involve two or more containers that need to be kept in sync. And as you have seen, two sequential atomic operations (whether with locks or without) are not together atomic. Basically, your approach to concurrency is just begging for deadlocks.

Comment: @NicolBolas Not at all. It depends on the problem. I've created a concurrent locking wrapper that is threadsafe, and every stl container can be passed into it. When using the wrapper, you can manipulate the object by concurrent or exclusive access.  Then if you need concurrent unorered_map, you use wrapper over it and grand thread-safety. It runs about 500 thousand stations without a problem.

However, that's not what I wanted to point to here. 
Instead, I was trying to find the solution to a lock-free wrapper.

Comment: @VítJaneček: As a datapoint, Java containers were originally threadsafe as you mention, and they deprecated all of them and replaced them with non-threadsafe versions, because the fine locking (A) caused performance problems and (B) caused developers to not realize they needed courser locks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, a sidenote.  `std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<T>>` gives atomic access to the *pointer*, and provides *no synchronization whatsoever* for the `T`. That's super important to note here. And your code shows that you're trying to synchronize the `T`, not the pointer, so the `atomic` is not doing what you think it is.  In order to use `std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<T>>`, you must treat the pointed-at `T` as `const`.

There's two ways to handle read-modify-write with arbitrary data in a thread safe way.  The first is, obviously, to use locks. This is usually faster to execute and due to its simplicity, usually less buggy, and is therefore highly suggested. If you *really* want to do this with atomic operations, it's difficult, and executes slower.

It usually looks something like this, where you make a deep copy of the pointed-at data, mutate the copy, and then attempt to replace the old data with the new data. If someone else has changed the data in the meantime, you throw it all away and start the whole mutation over.

```
template<class T, class F>
bool readModifyWrite(std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<T>>& container, F&& function) {
   do {
       const auto&& oldT = container.load();
       //first a deep copy, to enforce immutability
       auto&& newT = std::make_shared(oldT.get());
       //then mutate the T
       if (!function(*newT))
           return false; //function aborted
       //then attempt to save the modified T.
       //if someone else changed the container during our modification, start over
  } while(container.compare_exchange_strong(oldT, newT) == false);
    //Note that this may take MANY tries to eventually succeed.
    return true;
}
```

And then usage is similar to what you had:

```
auto&& container           = std::atomic(std::make_shared<std::unordered_set<int>>());
auto thread1               = std::jthread([&]([[maybe_unused]] std::stop_token token)
      {
          for (size_t i = 0; i < loopCount; i++)
          {
              readModifyWrite(container, [](auto& reader) {
                 reader.emplace(5);
                 return true;
              });
          }
      });

auto thread2 = std::jthread([&]([[maybe_unused]] std::stop_token token)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < loopCount; i++)
        {
              readModifyWrite(container, [](auto& reader) {
                 reader.erase(5);
                 return true;
              });
        }
    });
}
```

Note that since one thread is inserting `5` `loopCount` times, and the other is erasing `5` `loopCount` times, but they aren't synchronized between them, the first thread might write several times in a row (which is a no-op for a set) and then the second thread might erase several times in a row (which is a no-op for a set), so you don't really have guarantees about the end result here, but I'm assuming you knew that.

If, however, you wanted to use the mutations to synchronize, that gets quite a bit more complicated. The mutating function has to return if it succeeded or aborted, and then the caller of `readModifyWrite` has to handle the case where the modify aborted.  (Note that `readModifyWrite` effectively returns the value from the function, so it returns the value from the modify step.  The write step does not affect the return value)

```
auto thread1               = std::jthread([&]([[maybe_unused]] std::stop_token token)
      {
          for (size_t i = 0; i < loopCount; )
          {
              bool did_emplace = readModifyWrite(container, [](auto& reader) {
                 return reader.emplace(5);
              });
              if (did_emplace) i++;
          }
      });

auto thread2 = std::jthread([&]([[maybe_unused]] std::stop_token token)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < loopCount; )
        {
              bool did_erase = readModifyWrite(container, [](auto& reader) {
                 return reader.erase(5);
              });
              if (did_erase) i++;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Great answer. I thought about deep copy before, but I wasn't sure how to correctly synchronize modified value to origin value.  Also, memory overhead will be increased with this solution, but it will be lock-free, so it's what I need. Of course, selecting the best option depends on the problem ;).  You mentioned that synchronization does not happen when one thread inserts by loop 5times and the other erases it 5times, but I count with it.

Comment: @VítJaneček: Read-Copy-Update (RCU) is a known technique, but solving the deallocation problem without garbage collection (like in C++) requires some infrastructure, especially to keep readers fully efficient and read-only.  You have to make sure you don't deallocate while any thread is still potentially reading or worse writing some memory.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-copy-update.  I guess if you use `shared_ptr`'s ref counting, you're not getting fully read-only readers, but it might be a half-way tradeoff.